# laravel casts doubles the date sometimes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a web application supports multiple timezones, UTC is the default timezone and I used Laravel casts to read and set date times or times based on user timezone, but the problem I'm facing that sometimes its adding the difference in hours twice, lets say the difference between Istanbul and UTC two hours, its adding four.

the code is below, anyone faced something like this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Casts;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class TimezoneDatetime implements CastsAttributes
{

    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $date = Carbon::parse($value, config('app.default_timezone'))->setTimezone(detectUserTimezone());
            return $date;
        }

        if ($value instanceof Carbon) {
            return $value->copy()->setTimezone(detectUserTimezone());
        }

        return $value;
    }


    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $date = Carbon::parse($value, detectUserTimezone())->setTimezone(config('app.default_timezone'));
            return $date;
        }

        if ($value instanceof Carbon) {
            return $value->copy()->setTimezone(config('app.default_timezone'));
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the default timezone value here while setting the date?

Comment: The default timezone is UTC, I added it because I change config/app.php timezone during the runtime through middleware so I need another constant to stay without any changes.